# How to set requestFocus for TextField on ListView entire cell in flutter

Tags: listview, flutter, keyboard, textfield

I am developing flutter app with Listview, where each cell have **Text** and **TextField** inside Row.
I want to **open keyboard on entire cell click**,
But currently keyboard is only open when we hit on TextField area.

**I have try to set requestFocus on onTap but it is apply to all cell. i need it works for only taped cell.**

Here is code

```
new ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: displaySensorDataList.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                    return GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () => FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(myFocusNode),
                      child: new Card(
                        child: Container(
                          height: 50.0,
                          margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0,right: 20.0,),
                          child: new Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              new Text(
                                displaySensorDataList[i].name,
                              ),
                              new Expanded(
                                flex: 3,
                                child: new TextField(
                                  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                                  autofocus: false,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  })),
```